# Are Mersenne numbers with Mersenne prime exponent always prime?

Tags: prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

A Mersenne number is a number on the form $2^n-1$. For it to be prime, the number $n$ must be prime. My question is that if $n$ is another Mersenne prime, will $2^n-1$ be always prime?

It seems so, to me anyway.

Comment: If this were true, this would generate info itelyinfjnitely many mersenne primes!  We currently know of only 48.

Answer (score 2):

My own program found that $2^{2^{13} - 1} - 1$ is not a (probable) prime number, confirmed by Wolfram Alpha and https://oeis.org/A000043. Note that $M_{13} = 8191$ is prime and $M_{8191}$ is not.

Comment: Wolfram alpha says result unknown

Comment: For me is says it is not (after a few seconds), query was `isprime 2^(2^13-1)-1`. Anyway, $M_{8191}$ is not in the list of Mersenne primes.

Comment: Thanks. Doubt clarified

Answer (score 2):

https://oeis.org/A000043

We only know about finitely many Mersenne primes.  If your conjecture was true, then we could generate infinitely many Mersenne primes.

Comment: Yes. That would be true.